# iPhone returning same keydown event for (hash and 3) and (Asterisk and 8)

Tags: javascript, iphone, events, keycode

Am working on phone validation and have a requirement of auto formatting the input with phone no and only allow numeric characters to be added . However when i try to restrict the input using keydown and keypress, IPhone is allowing me to enter # and * . When i checked the keydown value , they both are same with 3 and 8 respectively (keycode 51 and 56). This works perfectly in Android browsers but fails in iPhone.

Anyone faced similar issue.

```js
$(formSelector + ' input[name^="phone"]').on('keydown keypress',function (e) {         
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter  
    if ( e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 9 || e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 13 ||   
        // Allow: Ctrl+A  
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||   
        // Allow: home, end, left, right  
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)
    ) {                
        // let it happen, don't do anything  
        return;  
    } else {  
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress  
        if (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105 ) ) {  
            e.preventDefault();   
        }              

});
```

I also tried one other method which was suggested in stackoverflow to bind input with 'input propertychange' events and then use pattern matching. but this works correct in IPhone , but fails in Android.

```js
$(formSelector + ' input[name^="phone"]').bind('input propertychange', function() {  
   var text = $(this).val();  
   if (isNaN(text)) {  
       $(this).val(text.replace(/[^\d]/gi, ''));  
   }  
});
```

Does anyone have a common solution for this problem ??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the [jQuery demo](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) show any differences in the events?

Comment: jQUeryDemo shows the same keycode. 3 and # are same and 8 and * are same. But the one differnce i found in mobile vs computer browser is that the shifkey becomes true in computer when entering # and * , but the same is false in mobile because we are not using any shift key

Comment: Are all the other properties (e.g. `shiftKey`) also the same?

Comment: Shiftkey remains false in mobile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  on('keydown keypress',function (e){});
```

First, triggers twice on iOS (no clue why), and `bind` fails on FireFox, so just use `$().keypress`.

Your filtering was letting through the right keycodes for the numbers you wanted, but, not catching the characters you needed to catch, at first I had a solution going which used e.orginialEvent.keyIdentifier to go after the misbehaving keys, but this failed dramatically on firefox.

In looking for a solution to that problem I found and modified code from this [page about keycodes and charcodes in Firefox](http://clipperhouse.com/2009/11/17/keycode-vs-charcode-vs-firefox/).

```
  $(formSelector).keypress(function (e) {
     var k = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
     var c = e.charCode;
     var isArrow = (c == 0 && k >= 37 && k <= 40);
     var isSpecial = ((k == 8) || (k == 9) || (k == 127)) || isArrow;   // backspace, tab, delete
     var isOK = (k >= 48 && k <= 57) ;  // numbers
     return isOK || isSpecial;
   });
```

Live Versions:

[Good Version, Tested on: iOS, Chrome, Firefox, Tested](http://projects.bygph.com/iOSPhoneNumbers/index.html)

[keyIdentifier version, Failed on: Firefox](http://projects.bygph.com/iOSPhoneNumbers/jsproblem2.html)

Comment: It triggers twice because two of the three events that fire when a key is pressed are being listened for (keydown, keyup, keypress).

Answer (score 1):

Try

`<input type="number">`

or

`<input pattern="[0-9]">`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:
      `<input oninput="filter(this,'1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0')">`

 And have this function in you list:


    `` function filter(`obj,allowed) { 
    var allowed = split("|");
    

    var c = 0
    for(c; c < allowed.length; c++)
    {
    

    oqj.value=obj.value.replace(allowed[c],"")
    
}

    } ``