# KeyDown event on iOS, no difference between 2 and @

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have an input where I want (apart from other formatting stuff) allow only digits. This is an easy thing to do with `keyDown` event:

```
field.keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.shiftKey) return false;
  var key = e.which;
  var is_numeric = ((key <= 57 && key >= 48) || (key <= 105 && key >= 96));
  // ...
  if (is_numeric && ..) {
    format_field();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This works very nicely, however I am having serious issue with iOS, as there are pairs of symbols-digits with the same keycode (for example `@` and `2` have both code 50, or `1` and `!` are both 49) and there is no differences in the remaining flags as well (`shiftKey`, `altKey`, 'ctrlKey` are false for both events). I have tested those events on: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ (see demo at the bottom of the page) and I failed to notice any difference between keyDown events for those pairs.

Is there absolutely no way of telling which key has been pressed or did I miss sth obvious?

Comment: Weird behaviour indeed... And it seems that when using a `keyPress` event the codes are differentiated properly (e.g 49 for `1` and 33 for `!`)

Comment: @spassas Yep, keyPress uses yet differnet keycodes, however it is triggered after the input value has been change, so the client will see the letter appear and disappear again if I use this event instead.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. It's obviously not a solution to your issue, I just noted it as an interesting remark, nothing more.

Comment: OK, apparantly this question is  a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469101/iphone-returning-same-keydown-event-for-hash-and-3-and-asterisk-and-8 (weird feeling to vote to close my own question :P) It seems there is no way to do this with keydown :(